# Resources invitation policy in Kolab 3.4

Tags: email, server-setup

When anybody reserves a resource, it's automatically accepted.

I'd like it to be manually accepted by the owner of the resource, so I do:

- Create "fool" resource in kolab-webadmin with email fool@domain.com
- Set user "boss" as owner of the resource
- Also set all access rights to user "boss" for this resource
- User "monkey" makes a new event from roundcube and reserves "fool"
- After creation, "monkey" receives en email confirming reservation
- "Boss" does not receive any kind of notification of the reservation just made
- However, "boss" can subscribe to "fool" Calendar and see the event there, he can even modify it and delete the resource "fool", thus "monkey" being notified and event updated.

Question one is:

- Why does not "boss" receive any notification of the resource reservation?

Also, I do not want resources to be assigned automatically, so I change in /etc/kolab/kolab.conf

```
[wallace]
#kolab_invitation_policy = ACT_ACCEPT_IF_NO_CONFLICT:domain.com, ACT_MANUAL
kolab_invitation_policy = ACT_MANUAL
```

But I see not effect on resources. Instead, all new users get LDAP attribute kolabInvitationPolice = ACT_MANUAL, but there is no such a field in Resources.

Second question is:

- Can I configure resources to be manually accepted by their owners?

Third and last question:

- Can be email fool@domain.com (attached to the resource) configured to receive email and how can I read it? (By default mail delivering system returns "no such user").

Thank you.